# How to select columns which are not null in SAP HANA?

Tags: hana

So I have a base table - `TRAINING`, which has 100 columns. Some of the columns will be completely NULL and some will contain Values. So say `COLUMN 1-20` are null and `COLUMN 21-100` are not NULL.

I have another table called - `CONFIGURATION`. It has only one column of type `VARCHAR`. This table contains the name of those columns from the TRAINING table that are not `NULL`. So it'll contain values - `COLUMN 21-100`.

What I want to do is- fetch the data of only those columns that are not NULL. So I want the output as the data points contained in table `COLUMN 21-100`. This number may be different every time and it can also be interleaved, say `COLUMN 1-10` is NULL and `COLUMN 11-25` not `NULL` and the remaining again NULL.

I am thinking of implementing inner Join but I do not have the table structure required for it.

Please provide some hint.

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Can you provide some example ?

Comment: Is the question about MySQL or HANA SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create dynamic SQL for that.

**First step** - create `ALL_COLUMNS` variable of `VARCHAR(5000)` data type. 
From your `CONFIGURATION` table select column names which you want to query. Then use `STRING_AGG` function to aggregate them into single value (in my example `COL1` is column from `CONFIGURATION` table). Assign output to the `ALL_COLUMNS` variable

**Second step** use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run dynamic SQL. Add `ALL_COLUMNS` variable as input for that query.

Here is the examplary code:

```
DO
BEGIN

/* First Step - create string with all column names separated by comma*/

    DECLARE ALL_COLUMNS VARCHAR(5000);

    SELECT  STRING_AGG(COL1,',' ORDER BY COL1)  INTO ALL_COLUMNS FROM CONFIGURATION;

/*Second Step - create dynamic SQL including variable from First Step*/

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('SELECT ' || :ALL_COLUMNS  || ' FROM "TRAINING" ');

END
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the perfect solution. Just a follow up question - Why do we really need Dynamic sql there ? Can't we just use  `ALL_COLUMNS` variable in select query to fetch the results like we would normally do ? I have tried the following query and it doesnt work . Can you explain why ? `SELECT :columns from "ATTRIBUTE_TABLE";`

Comment: This is because `:columns` variable is a string and SQL engine will treat it as fixed value i,e: for string 'col1,col2,col3', it will just display one column with multiplicated value of col1,col2,col3 in each row.